# Return List<ComplexType> from ObjectResult<ComplexType> - and will it be XML?

Tags: c#, wcf, entities, complextype

I've created a complex type using the entities framework for the results of a stored procedure I've written on a database I'm connected to. I'm now writing a web service to return the results from the stored procedure (i.e. a collection of the complex type I've just created). I've been specifically asked to return SOAP XML from the WCF service. It was my understanding that a WCF service would 'automatically' deal with returning the most appropriate response based on it's consumers config - so would returning a ObjectResult be succesfully 'translated' to XML? Or must I convert to List<> first? And if so - is there a more efficient way than simply looping through the object result?

Thanks a lot, any help seriously appreciated.

EDIT: I must explain that the consumer in this case will be server-side code, I just need to make sure it *does* return XML should the client be in request of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `ObjectResult<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, you can use `IEnumerable` extension methods and get an array of T using:

```
ObjectResult<ComplexType> res = ....;
ComplexType[] array = res.ToArray<ComplexType>();  // res.ToArray() is also fine because of type inference
```

Also make sure `ComplexType` is serializable.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ken, appreciate it. How can I make sure the ComplexType is serializable? I'm assuming it needs to be to be converted to XML.

Comment: Precisely: your class must be serializable so it can be translated to XML. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731073.aspx for example.

Comment: My class is a complex class from the entities model though - does this make things anymore trickier??

Comment: And what I forgot, is to add the ns --> using System.Linq;

Answer (score -2):

we can call directly `ToList()`

```
using (var ts = new YourEntityFramework())
{
    List<complex_object> lst = ts.YourSp().ToList();
}
```

ObjectResult is converted by using ToList(). so then we can use ObjectResult on our data access layer and List to pass it other layers .

Comment: Is there a relation between `DB_EmployeeEntities`, `GetSPITems` and the original question?

Comment: Doesn't work because of: 'ObjectResult<T>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'ObjectResult<T>' could be found